# Transition left div width over right div and vise versa

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Please refer to this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b53te5qb/1/

I am attempting to make each of these div widths transition nicely over the other.

Right now it is an instant effect, but I would like for it to transition smoothly. When I attempt the transition it starts to get buggy.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="color left"></div>
    <div class="color right"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS so far:

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}

.color {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    transition: width 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s linear;
}

.color:hover {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.left {
    background-color: #ff0;
}

.right {
    background-color: #0ff;
}
```

I am open to restructuring this however I would need to in order to complete the task. I just provided this as a base example.

Comment: That can be done like this https://jsfiddle.net/xm5dwzsL/ though based on what these 2 elements might contain, one might need to be doing this in another way.

Comment: only one in absolute position will do, z-index can be use for the overlapping issue https://jsfiddle.net/b53te5qb/1/

Comment: @GCyrillus You posted the same fiddle link as OP has in the question :)

Comment: @LGSon ah, could be number 11 ? https://jsfiddle.net/b53te5qb/11/  *edit* initial was actually from https://jsfiddle.net/b53te5qb/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/prowseed/b53te5qb/10/

Two techniques, one with flexbox and one with position absolute, pick any :)

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 666px;
    display:flex;
}

.color {
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
    transition: .3s;
}

.color:hover {
    flex-basis:100%;
}

.outer2 {
  margin-top:100px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 666px;
}

.outer2:hover .color {
  width:0;
}

.outer2 .color {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:50%;
  }

  .outer2 .color + .color {
    left:auto;
    right:0;
  }

  .outer2 .color:hover {
    width:100%;
    z-index:2;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're just doing this with solid colors, I would transition `transform: scaleX()`. Using `transition` with `transform` will give you better performance.

```css
.outer {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}

.color {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    transition: transform 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s linear;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.color:hover {
    transform: scaleX(2);
}

.left {
    background-color: #ff0;
}

.right {
    background-color: #0ff;
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="color left"></div>
    <div class="color right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to position them absolutely in order to avoid them from moving.

https://jsfiddle.net/b53te5qb/6/

I would highly recommend not transitioning the width, much better would be to transition `transform: translateX()`, since it will be hardware accelerated and much smoother: https://jsfiddle.net/b53te5qb/8/.

It still needs polishing, but the idea is there. (note the `overflow: hidden` to avoid showing the excess.) Another improvement would be to have two elements on top (50%/50% width) that trigger the hover via javascript, since when the elements move it's difficult to keep the hover on them, or to remove the hover without leaving the `.outer` component.

Hope it helps.